# VB.net - grouping identical values then manipulating the result

Tags: vb.net

I have found some similar questions but none that hit what I am looking for. Lets say I have an array of 10 values for fruit :

```
fruit(1) = "apple"
fruit(2) = "orange"
fruit(3) = "banana"
fruit(4) = "cherry"
fruit(5) = "peach"
fruit(6) = ""
fruit(7) = ""
fruit(8) = ""
fruit(9) = ""
fruit(10) = ""
```

now, i have a statement that says that fruit(6)="apple", making the array :

```
fruit(1) = "apple"
fruit(2) = "orange"
fruit(3) = "banana"
fruit(4) = "cherry"
fruit(5) = "peach"
fruit(6) = "apple"
fruit(7) = ""
fruit(8) = ""
fruit(9) = ""
fruit(10) = ""
```

I want to have a sub that will group like items and  only store it once. So,

```
fruit(1) = "2 x apple"
fruit(2) = "orange"
fruit(3) = "banana"
fruit(4) = "cherry"
fruit(5) = "peach"
fruit(6) = ""
fruit(7) = ""
fruit(8) = ""
fruit(9) = ""
fruit(10) = ""
```

and then next time i add an apple it goes to "3 x apple" and so on.

so in pseudo code i want it to

```
look for duplicate values
count how many duplicates 
alter the original item
delete all but the newly altered entry
```

what's the simplest and most elegant way to do this in vb.net? is there a way to do it without LINQ?

Comment: You could use a Dictionary(Of String, Integer) where the key is the fruit and the value is the count. Just check if the key already exists, if yes then increase the count. By the way, arrays start at index 0 not 1.

Comment: @the_lotus You can get away with arrays indexing at 1 or 0 with VB.NET, depending on how you declare the array--if you `Dim fruit(10) As Integer` you will get an array that goes from `fruit(0)` to `fruit(10)`, it's probably best to be consistent with the rest of .NET though.

Answer (score 0):

@the_lotus is right, you can use a dictionary

```
   Dim fruits As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

   Sub AddFruit(fruitname As String)
      If fruits.ContainsKey(fruitname) Then
         fruits.Item(fruitname) += 1
      Else
         fruits.Add(fruitname, 1)
      End If
   End Sub
```

And then return

```
   Function NumberOfFruit(fruitname As String) As String
      Return fruits.Item(fruitname) & " x " & fruitname
   End Function
```